# How to move image in Glcontrol in OpenTk

Tags: opentk

I am new to opentk I want to move image from left to right smoothly. How can I do this?

I have tried moving viewport but it doesn't look smooth rendering.

int cnt = 1920;
public void DrawImage(int image)
{

```
        GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(cnt, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight));
        cnt--;
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        //GL.Ortho(0, 1920, 0, 1080, 0, 1);

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, image);

        
        RunShaders();

        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.PopMatrix();

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PopMatrix();

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);

        //ErrorCode ec = GL.GetError();
        //if (ec != 0)
        //    System.Console.WriteLine(ec.ToString());
        //Console.Read();
        glControl1.SwapBuffers();
    }
```

Comment: Use `GL.Translate`